# migrated my website but one link doesn't work php?

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, backup

so I just migrated my website, bwa.org/main to the staging site for testing. the staging site is stagebwa.org. I used backupbuddy and importbuddyphp to migrate the site for the most part it was fine. I've had to fix some little things but I think it's because during the backup buddy process, they asked me if I wanted to make the site homepage stagebwa.org/main but I chose stagebwa.org. I think this has caused a lot of problems with the search function.

here's how it's supposed to work. if you click 'begin specialized search' without inputing parameters, it will spit out all users in the results.  from the regular site: http://www.bwa.org/main/find-a-writer/

here's the staging site where it doesn't work. when you click the same button here, it brings you to the site's version of a '404 not found page'. http://www.stagebwa.org/find-a-writer/

The php logic is the same so I know that's not the problem. I think it's because clicking the search button reloads the page as stagebwa.org/main/find-a-writer and that's messing the whole thing up. I'm pretty sure getting the page to reload on stagebwa.org/find-a-writer will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>`'s action attribute is relative, `<form action="/main/find-a-writer">`.

http://www.bwa.org/main/find-a-writer does exists
http://www.stagebwa.org/main/find-a-writer does not
http://www.stagebwa.org/find-a-writer does exist

If you remove the `/main` from the form action to make it just `<form action="/find-a-writer">` it works just fine.

I have a feeling you that perhaps you didn't account for the fact that the live site lives on a subdirectory and not the root URL when you cloned it - but it should be as simple as that, just removing `/main` on the staging site

Comment: No worries, glad to help!